# Scala: How to find matching items in a List

Tags: scala

There is a guest coming for lunch and at each table there is one person (bob, peter, simon or sarah) and on that table there is one fruit bowl.

I need to score the matches of fruit in order to decide which person/table the guest should with/at.

My thinking is that I need to give each person a score based on the amount of matches they have with the guests fruit. So I need to compare a `List[Fruit]` with a `List[Fruit]` then return the `Person`

I need to return a Map as per below

```scala
  case class Person(str: String, value: List[Fruit])

  case class Fruit(fruit: String)

  val guest: Person = Person("Unknown", List(Fruit("Apple"), Fruit("Pear"), Fruit("Grapes")))
  
  val bob: Person = Person("Bob", List(Fruit("Apple"), Fruit("Pear"), Fruit("Grapes"))) // 3
  val peter: Person = Person("Peter", List(Fruit("Apple"), Fruit("Pineapple"), Fruit("Mango"))) // 1
  val simon: Person = Person("Simon", List(Fruit("Apple"), Fruit("Pear"), Fruit("Mango"))) // 2
  val sarah: Person = Person("sarah", List(Fruit("Pear"), Fruit("Grapes"), Fruit("Mango"))) // 2

  Map( 3 ->
    Person("Bob", List(Fruit("Apple"), Fruit("Pear"), Fruit("Grapes"))),
    2 -> Person("Simon", List(Fruit("Apple"), Fruit("Pear"), Fruit("Mango"))),
    2 -> Person("sarah", List(Fruit("Pear"), Fruit("Grapes"), Fruit("Mango"))),
    1 -> Person("Peter", List(Fruit("Apple"), Fruit("Pineapple"), Fruit("Mango")))
  )
```

Comment: That `Map` will only have 3 elements because the key `2` is repeated so the first instance will be replaced by the second. The `Map` needs to have a list of people for each count.

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answer should work, but it is kind of like imperative approach, and personally I wouldn't use mutation as far as possible, I would recommend using the intersection of fruits set in order to find the fruits in common:

```scala
val persons = List(bob, peter, simon, sarah)

persons.map { person => 
  val fruitsInCommon = (person.value.toSet & guest.value.toSet).size
  fruitsInCommon -> person
}.sortBy(_._1).toMap
```

You can also use `.view` on the persons if you'd like to.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Your solution seems to eliminate simon. I guess a Map can't have the same key twice. Not sure how to get around this. I guess I would have to create a case class PersonWithScore and then create an ordered list based on that score?

Comment: Like this maybe: 

```
persons.map { person =>
    val fruitsInCommon = (person.value.toSet & guest.value.toSet).size
    PersonWithScore(person, fruitsInCommon)
  }
```

Or can you think of a better way?

Comment: @fullStackRyan Well if you don’t really need a Map, you can also store it into a list, and it makes sense, otherwise you can also reverse the key values and use the map, like instead of “fruitsInCommon -> person”, you can do “person -> fruitsInCommon”, and sort based on the second element of tuple instead of first element. (Although sorting in a map doesn’t really make sense, does it?)

Comment: @fullStackRyan You can make the map contain a list of people to avoid the bug in this answer. And ignore the sort, it is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This will give a map that groups people by number of fruit they have in common with the guest:

```
val persons = List(bob, peter, simon, sarah)

persons.groupMap(_.value.intersect(guest.value).size)(_.str)

// Map(1 -> List(Peter), 2 -> List(Simon, sarah), 3 -> List(Bob))
```

Using `Set` would be more efficient, perhaps as a calculated value on `Person`:

```
case class Person(str: String, value: List[Fruit]) {
  lazy val fruitSet = value.toSet
}

persons.groupMap(_.fruitSet.intersect(guest.fruitSet).size)(_.str)
```

Comment: Well lazy val is not actually “calculated”. And also, why having fruits both as List and Set?

Comment: The order of fruit might matter, and best not to change the original data types from the question. Not sure what that first remark means, the value of fruitSet will be calculated the first time it is needed.